# Express.js: How to pass req object to middleware w/o creating a new route w/ Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm new both to Express.js and to StackOverflow; I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question. I checked, but didn't see anything relevant.

So, I'm using Multer + Express to allow a user to upload an image, which will be named `'${username}.{extension}'`, to a server-side /uploads/ folder. I don't want users to be able to save more than one image on the server (i.e. no "user1.jpg" and "user1.png"). To accomplish this, I wrote the following middleware:

```
function deleteUserImage(req){
    const acceptedExtensions = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tif', '.tiff', '.JPG', '.bmp'];
    acceptedExtensions.forEach(char => {
        if(fs.existsSync(`./uploads/${req.cookies.username+char}`)){
            fs.unlinkSync(`./uploads/${req.cookies.username+char}`);
        }
    })
}
```

I then was able to get the functionality I wanted with the following routes:

```
app.post('/process_upload-image', (req, res, next) => { //User sends post req w/ image file
    deleteUserImage(req) //images for that user are cleared.
    next();
})

app.post('/process_upload-image', upload.single('user-image'), (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/welcome'); //user is redirected after multer uploads the image.
})
```

I was wondering if this was best-practices, however, since you end up with two routes listening at the same URI? Is there a way to pass req to deleteUserImage(), then call upload.single()...all in one route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply chain multiple middlewares on one route. Change the `deleteUserImage` function to:

```
function deleteUserImage(req, res, next){
   const acceptedExtensions = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.tif', '.tiff', '.JPG', '.bmp'];
   acceptedExtensions.forEach(char => {
       if(fs.existsSync(`./uploads/${req.cookies.username+char}`)){
           fs.unlinkSync(`./uploads/${req.cookies.username+char}`);
       }
   })

   next()
}
```

and then remove the first route and change the second one to:

```
app.post('/process_upload-image', deleteUserImage, upload.single('user-image'), (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect('/welcome');
})
```

Comment: I thought there must be something like that. Thanks!! I've upvoted the answer, but I don't have enough rep for it to show.